# Can "find that" be followed by a subjunctive clause, i.e. bare form of verb is used instead of inflectional form

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, subjunctives

I saw the following sentence in a book that I'm reading:

> We will therefore find it imperative that the real number system which we're in the process of constructing also exhibit these qualities.

It seems quite obvious to me that "the real number system" is a singular noun phrase but the verb is "exhibit" which seems not to agree with the noun. I think this may be the case of subjunctive form or it's just a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a subjunctive construction, but not because of *find*. The subordinate clause here is an extraposed object following the adjective *imperative*, which does license subjunctive clauses. Some examples:

(1) *It is imperative that she know how to find the information.*

(2) *It was imperative that he find some sense of salvation, however feeble.*

(3) *She says that it's imperative that she speak with you immediately.*

When it comes to the verb *find*, it has two complements: a direct object (the pronoun *it*) and a predicative complement realised by an adjective phrase. Here's the same structure in its bare-bones version:

(4) *I find it silly.*

In your example, this structure is combined with extraposition, with *it* being a dummy pronoun.